# How can I extract and save text using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, text, extract

No extracted data output to data2.txt? What goes wrong to the code?

**MyFile.txt**

```
ex1,fx2,xx1
mm1,nn2,gg3
EX1,hh2,ff7
```

This is my desired output in data2.txt:

```
ex1,fx2,xx1
EX1,hh2,ff7
```

```
#! /DATA/PLUG/pvelasco/Softwares/PERLINUX/bin/perl -w

my $infile  ='My1.txt';
my $outfile ='data2.txt';

open IN,  '<', $infile  or die "Cant open $infile:$!";
open OUT, '>', $outfile or die "Cant open $outfile:$!";

while (<IN>) {   
  if (m/EX$HF|ex$HF/) {
    print OUT $_, "\n";      
    print $_;   
  }
}

close IN;
close OUT;
```

Comment: Use three argument open.

Answer (score 5):

This regex makes no sense:

```
m/EX$HF|ex$HF/
```

Is $HF supposed to be a variable? What are you trying to match?

Also, the second line in *every* Perl script you write should be:

```
use strict;
```

It will make Perl catch such mistakes and tell you about them, rather than silently ignoring them.

Comment: ... and the third should be `use warnings`.

Comment: Well why doesn't he just add -Mstrict to the first line?

Answer (score 3):

```
while (<IN>) {
  if (m/^(EX|ex)\d.*/) {   
    print OUT "$_";      
    print $_;   
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, if you don't need the (debug?) output of all lines in the input file, you can reduce this to the one-liner

    perl -ne 'print if /^(EX|ex)\d/'

Comment: perl golf has its place, but I'd rather people put readable code into production.

Comment: This *is* simple enough to use a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this seems like stating the bleeding obvious, but what's wrong with

```
grep -i ^ex < My1.txt > data2.txt
```

... or if you really want to do it in perl (and there's nothing wrong with that):

```
perl -ne '/^ex/i && print' < My1.txt > data2.txt
```

This assumes the purpose of the request is to find lines that start with EX, with case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, but name the input file `My1.txt` instead of `MyFile.txt` I get the desired output - except with empty lines, which you can remove by removing the `, "\n"` from the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

The filenames don't match.

```
open(my $inhandle, '<', $infile)   or die "Cant open $infile: $!";
open(my $outhandle, '>', $outfile) or die "Cant open $outfile: $!";

while(my $line = <$inhandle>) {   

    # Assumes that ex, Ex, eX, EX all are valid first characters
    if($line =~ m{^ex}i) {         # or   if(lc(substr $line, 0 => 2) eq 'ex') {
        print { $outhandle } $line;      
        print $line;
    }
}
```

And yes, always **always** *use strict;*

You could also *chomp $line* and (if using perl 5.10) *say $line* instead of *print "$line\n"*.

Comment: What are the braces for in this line?         print { $outhandle } $line;

Comment: It helps avoid mistakes like...  print $outhandle, $line;  (the comma means print won't recognise $outhandle as a file handle).   Its a recommendation from "Perl Best Practises" by Damian Conway.