# How can I extract text, save it, then output it to web?

Tags: perl, search, cgi, extract

I am [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211260/perl-extract-text-then-save<br) for HF50(HF$HF) for example in "MyFile.txt" so that the extracted data must save to "save.txt". The data on "save.txt" now extracted again and fill the parameters and output on my table. But when I tried the code, I've got no output and "save.txt" is blank.?

Var $HF is not recognized whatever I type. Please help.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";

use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($file,$line,$tester,$HF,$keyword);
my ($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8,$f9,$f10,$f11,$f12,$f13,$f14,$f15,$f16,$f17,$f18,$f19);

my $keyWord=param('keyword');
$HF=$keyWord;

my $infile='MyFile.txt';
my $outfile='save.txt';

open (my $inhandle, '<',$infile) or die "Can't open $infile:$!";
open (my $outhandle, '>', $outfile) or die "Can't open $outfile:$!";


while (my $line=<$inhandle>){
if ($line=~ m/HF$HF/i) {
print {$outhandle}$line;
print $line;

print "<HTML>";
print "<head>";
print "<body bgcolor='#4682B4'>";
print "<title>FUSION SHIFT REPORT</title>";
print "<div align='left'>";
print "<FORM METHOD='get'        ACTION='http://Shielex.com/pe/mrigos/mainhead.html'>";
print "<b>SEACRH:</b>";
print "<INPUT TYPE='text' NAME='rec' SIZE='12' MAXLENGHT='40'>";
print "<INPUT TYPE='submit' value='go'>";
print "</form>";
print "<TABLE CELLPADDING='1' CELLSPACING='1' BORDER='1' bordercolor=black  width='100%'>";
print "<TR>";

print "<td width='11%'bgcolor='#00ff00'><font size='2'>TESTER No.</td>";
print "<td width='10%'bgcolor='#00ff00'><font size='2'>DATE</td>";

print "<td width='11%'bgcolor='#00ff00'><font size='2'>DEVICE NAME</td>";
print "<td bgcolor='#00ff00'><font size='2'>TEST PROGRAM</td>";

print "<td width='10%'bgcolor='#00ff00'><font size='2'>SMSLOT</td>";

print "<td width='12%'bgcolor='#00ff00'><font size='2'>LOADBOARD</td>";


print "<td width='10%'bgcolor='#00ff00'><font size='2'>CATEGORY</td>";
print "<td width='13%'bgcolor='#00ff00'><font size='2'>ROOT CAUSE 1</td>";
print "<td width='13%'bgcolor='#00ff00'><font size='2'>ROOT CAUSE 2</td>";
print "</tr>";
print "<TR>";

$file='save.txt';
open(F,$file)||die("Could not open $file");
while ($line=<F>)
{
my @cells=($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8,$f9,$f10,$f11,$f12,$f13,$f14,$f15,$f16,$f17,$f18,$f19)=   split ',',$line;

print "<TD bgcolor='#ADD8E6'><font size='2'>$f2</TD>";
print "<TD bgcolor='#ADD8E6'><font size='2'>$f3</TD>";

print "<TD bgcolor='#ADD8E6'><font size='2'>$f5</TD>";
print "<TD bgcolor='#ADD8E6'><font size='2'>$f6</TD>";

print "<TD bgcolor='#ADD8E6'><font size='2'>$f8</TD>";

print "<TD bgcolor='#ADD8E6'><font size='2'>$f10</TD>";
print "<TD bgcolor='#ADD8E6'><font size='2'>$f17</TD>";
print "<TD bgcolor='#ADD8E6'><font size='2'>$f18</TD>";
print "<TD bgcolor='#ADD8E6'><font size='2'>$f19</TD>";
print "</tr>";

}
}
}
close F;
print "</TABLE>";
print "</body>";
print "<html>";
```

=**MyFile.txt data**=
1,HF50,13-OCT-08,04:17:53,761503BZZGR-62,B2761503BP22.EVA,DWP,DWP,Calibration
2,HF60,13-OCT-08,04:17:53,761503BZZGR-62,B2761503BP22.EVA,DWP,DWP,Calibration
1,HF50,13-OCT-08,04:17:53,761503BZZGR-62,B2761503BP22.EVA,DWP,DWP,Calibration

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this as a CGI script? In that case, you probably don't have permission to open a file for writing. Did you check the error log to see if your message from `die` is in there?

You might want to check out [Troubleshooting Perl CGI scripts](http://brian-d-foy.cvs.sourceforge.net/*checkout*/brian-d-foy/CGI_MetaFAQ/troubleshooting_CGI.html). Go through all of the steps without skipping any. When you get stuck, you have most of the imformation you need to help us help you.

Good luck, :)

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot,,Im on the next stage of my program:)

Answer (score 0):

You never close `$outfile` so it doesn't get flushed. But maybe you want to store the data in an array instead?

As an aside, you should always use the three-argument form of `open()` and you should also always use absolute paths when working with CGI programs, as in many situations, the "current directory" is not what you think it is.

Answer (score -1):

First, Perl's output is by nature buffered. So, unless you use some explicit method, there's no guarantee that the physical file will have anything to read. As somebody mentioned, you'll have to flush the output somehow. My comments are below in the code. (You could also do this by closing the output file and opening it in *append* mode after you've read from it.)

Second, it doesn't seem like you want to do what it looks like you want to do. If everything was flushed perfectly to the file, you're requesting an html header *per input line*. So as I added lines into the input, it printed out that many search boxes. I don't expect that is what you wanted.

Here's a more *perl-ified* code:

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
use IO::File;
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($file,$line,$HF); #,$tester,$HF,$keyword);
# don't pollute -> my ($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8,$f9,$f10
# ,$f11,$f12,$f13,$f14,$f15,$f16,$f17,$f18,$f19);


# my $keyWord=param('keyword'); <-- if you're not going to do anything with $keyWord
$HF=param('keyword'); # <- assign it to the variable you're going to use

my $infile='MyFile.txt';
my $outfile='save.txt';

open (my $inhandle, '<',$infile) or die "Can't open $infile:$!";
open (my $outhandle, '>', $outfile) or die "Can't open $outfile:$!";
# this would flush -> my $outhandle = IO::File->new( ">$outfile" );

print q{Content-type:text/html

<HTML>
<head>
<title>FUSION SHIFT REPORT</title>
<style type="text/css">
.header { background-color : #0f0; font-size : 12pt }
.detail { background-color : #ADD8E6; font-size : 12pt }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor='#4682B4'>
<div align='left'>
<FORM METHOD='get' ACTION='http://Shielex.com/pe/mrigos/mainhead.html'>
<b>SEACRH:</b>
<input type='text' name='rec' size='12' maxlenght='40'>
<input type='submit' value='go'>
</form>
<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='1' bordercolor=black  width='100%'>
<tr>
  <td class="header" width='11%'>TESTER No.</td>
  <td class="header" width='10%'>DATE</td>
  <td class="header" width='11%'>DEVICE NAME</td>
  <td class="header" >TEST PROGRAM</td>
  <td class="header" width='10%'>SMSLOT</td>
  <td class="header" width='12%'>LOADBOARD</td>
  <td class="header" width='10%'>CATEGORY</td>
  <td class="header" width='13%'>ROOT CAUSE 1</td>
  <td class="header" width='13%'>ROOT CAUSE 2</td>
</tr>
}; 

my $hf_str = ",HF$HF,";
# OO -> $outhandle->autoflush(); <- set autoflush
while (my $line=<$inhandle>){
    next unless index( $line, $hf_str ) > -1;
    # OO -> $outhandle->print( $line );
    #       $outhandle->flush(); <- if autoflush not set, do it manually
    print *{$outhandle} $line;
    print "<tr>"
        , ( map { qq{<td class="detail">$_</td>} } 
            split ',', $line
           )
        , "</tr>\n"
        ;
}
print q{
</table>
</body>
</html>
};
```